# Block SSH access from outside LAN

Tags: ssh, vpn, git

I have an Ubuntu server machine that hosts Redmine and git repositories in a DMZ.
The only users who have an SSH access are the administrators.
Users from outside need to have access to Git and the web interface of Redmine, but I would like that SSH access is restricted to connections from inside the network (we have a VPN set up, so even from outside I would be able to SSH in the server through it).

How can I prevent SSH access from outside the LAN, still allowing Git access?

Thanks a lot in advance!

R

Comment: Just a side question, why is it in a DMZ? Why not just forward the ports that are used by the server and block the rest?

Comment: It's the setup they chose for school where I work. All the internal servers are split into those that are visible from outside (and therefore are put in the DMZ) and those which are "internal only".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSH (which I'm assuming is what you are using) [has an `AllowUsers` option](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5):

> **AllowUsers** - This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces. If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized. By default, login is allowed for all users. If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts. The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: `DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, and finally `AllowGroups`.

Edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and add this to the bottom of it:

```
AllowUsers git adam@192.168.0.* bob@192.168.0.* cliff@192.168.0.* david@192.168.0.*
```

If that doesn't work (and this way might actually be cleaner) [you can use the `Match` option](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Limit_access_to_openssh_features_with_the_Match_keyword.html) together with `AllowUsers`:

```
# This is the default setting (only allow GIT access)
AllowUsers git 

# This is the setting that is ONLY available if you are SSHing from the LAN (allow the listed users)
Match Address 192.168.0.*
    AllowUsers git adam bob cliff dave
```

Comment: That should theoretically be possible, though I can't test it on the current machine. Try that code, and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking for (and couldn't find googling), I'll test it right now, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @RH6 I added a second option which is a bit easier to read and change. You can try and see if that works as well.

Comment: @RH6 Really, my untested code actually worked? Did you test both the blocking and accepting? And remember to restart the server (`sudo service ssh restart`) after making the changes? If so, wonderful! :)

Comment: Haven't tested the second option yet, I am going to do it now. The first one works, I've tried with a few virtual machines trying to log in with allowed/blocked access and it does exactly what you said. :)

Comment: Yes, the second one works too perfectly, thanks again :)

Comment: I did some more playing with it. Right now it displays something like _"connection refused"_, but you can add a message telling users _why_ the connection was refused like this: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/2f5ee3ca63527b03184d

Answer (score 2):

you can use your systems iptables. This three lines would do the magic

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

maybe you do have to adjust the parameters like the Lan ip addresses.

if your vpn users gets routed to eg 192.169.8.0/24 you have to adjust that and add also

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

before you add the drop line, because if you do not, only packages on port 22 are accepted if the owner has either a 192.168.0.0/24 or a localhost address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was my first guess, but wouldn't this kill all the git accesses -- which happen to be on the same port?

Comment: yes, but you can't say if it is a git over ssh access or a ssh access, because there is no difference between standard ssh access and git access, because it's standard ssh transfer, but normal and special git content

Comment: True, but in my setup the git user is password-less (as explained in the redmine-git-hosting setup) and it has a git-shell behind, so attackers cannot go past this (sorry, I have forgotten mentioning this in the description!)